# Автоматическая отправка на e-mail

Tags: android, email

Возникла необходимость автоматической отправки сообщений на произвольные `e-mail` адреса(пользователь заранее настраивает что когда и кому отправить). [отправка `email` средствами системы](http://captainandroid.blogspot.ru/2012/01/email.html) -  здесь описано как отправить например с `gmail` клиента. А возможно ли, чтобы пользователь заранее выбрал какой клиент использовать и как это сделать? И еще один вопрос - возможна ли отправка без участия пользователя, т.е. чтобы, когда сработает время отправки, пользователю в клиенте не пришлось нажимать "отправить", а все отправилось само.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что предлагает [[@nullptr](/users/3689/nullptr)](/users/3689/nullptr) это не есть в духе `Android`, то есть так как бы можно, но не стоит.

Почитайте как это сделать здесь: [Отправка E-Mail средствами Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112450/) .

Comment: Читала, это одна из первых статей, на которую я наткнулась, скачала исходник, запустила, при попытке отправки приложение закрывается с ошибкой.

Comment: Не работает у меня это приложение вот такой лог:
05-21 12:16:08.705: I/exception(394): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
05-21 12:16:08.705: I/exception(394):   nested exception is:
05-21 12:16:08.705: I/exception(394):  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
Подскажите, пожалуйста что это значит?